# How to increment a count from a created element from a button

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom

Trying to figure out how I can get a count to work, after a user has entered a movie and submitted it so that the element would be created in a table.

There would be a button in the created element. How can I get make button increment a count that would also show up in the created element.

```
class Movie {
    constructor(title, year, cost) {
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}

class UI {
    createMovie(movie) {
        const list = document.getElementById('movie-list');
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = `
            <td>${movie.title}</td>
            <td>${movie.year}</td>
            <td>${movie.cost}</td>
            <td class="count"><td>
            <input type="submit" value="Watched" class="btn2"></input>
            <td><a href="#" class="delete">X</a></td>
        `;
        list.appendChild(row);
    }

    getMovie() {

    }

    addMovieWatchCount() {
        document.querySelector('.btn2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            let count = 0
            let numOfMovie = document.querySelector('.count').innerHTML = count;
            numOfMovie.appendChild(count);
        });
    }

    deleteMovie(target) {
        if(target.className === 'delete') {
            target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
    }

    clearMovieFields() {
        document.getElementById('movie').value = '';
        document.getElementById('year').value = '';
        document.getElementById('cost').value = '';
    }
}

//Event Handling

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    const title = document.getElementById('movie').value;
    const year = document.getElementById('year').value;
    const cost = document.getElementById('cost').value;
    const movie = new Movie(title, year, cost);
    const ui = new UI();
    ui.createMovie(movie);
    ui.clearMovieFields();
    e.preventDefault();
});

document.getElementById('movie-list').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const ui = new UI();
    ui.deleteMovie(e.target);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The user clicks the "Watched" button in created 'input' element, in the table and it should increment the content of a created 'th' element to 1, and so on.

Comment: This question will get more attention if you would add the relevant HTML, or even better, a working snippet, so that we can see what the issue is by running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try generating a unique per-movie class for each `<tr>` (like `btn2-${movie.title}`) added in `createMovie` and then also take a movie parameter in `addMovieWatchCount` to specifically bind a click listener to that specific button instead of just the first matching element.